# moving a div on mousemove inside another div

Tags: jquery, css, html, mousemove

I am trying to make a div which is inside a container div move in the opposite direction of the mouse on the X axis (only left and right).

this is what I have so far:

html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.container { width: 450px; height: 52px; border: 1px #000 solid; position: relative; }
.box { width: 50px; height: 50px; border: 1px #000 solid; position: absolute; right: 200px; }
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div.container').mousemove(function(e){
        var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
      if ($('div.box').css('right') <= '400') {
          $('div.box').css({'right': x}); 
      }
  });
});
```

JSfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/eyalbin/qQmu7/49/

for some reason the function stops working after a couple of seconds.

can anyone help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cGZxv/)

You wrote

`if ($('div.box').css('right') <= '400')`

instead of

`if (x <= 400)`

:)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('div.container').on('mousemove',function(e){
    var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;

      $('div.box').css({'right': x}); 

   });
});
```

Check This link Working fine dude...

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qQmu7/59/)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div.container').mousemove(function(e){
      var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
      if ((x <= 400)) {
          $('div.box').css({'right': x}); 
      }
  });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qQmu7/57/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#parent .child').mousemove( function(e) {


       var parent_x = this.offsetLeft; //get parent position
       var parent_y = this.offsetTop;      

       var mouseX   =  e.pageX; //get mouse move position
       var mouseY   =  e.pageY;

       var boxPositionX = mouseX-parent_x+5;
       var boxPositionY = mouseY-parent_y+5;

       $('.hover-box',this).css({'top': boxPositionY,'left': boxPositionX});
    });
```

///////// CSS

```
.hover-box{
   position:absolute;
}
```