# JQuery: Find if element is over another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a group of (dynamically added) div tags which the user can drag around the screen. What I need to happen is when the user drags (using JQuery draggable) one of the divs near to another div for a line / border to appear, and then the divs to lock together, similar to how Google docs presentation and MS PowerPoint do when you do something similar with a textbox or image.

I guess what I am trying to detect is if the borders of two divs are over each other, and give visual feedback if they are, in the form of the borders which are above each other changing colour.

Comment: Sounds good, now provide what you tried so far to prove you've got an issue with your code, rather than expecting us to do the code for you

Comment: I have no idea how to set about this task, and I am asking for any help on how to detect this type of event. ie. How do you detect if borders overlap?

Comment: possible duplicate of [moving a div on mousemove inside another div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270597/moving-a-div-on-mousemove-inside-another-div)

Comment: I marked this question as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270597/moving-a-div-on-mousemove-inside-another-div, which might not be duplicated, but you can start there.

Comment: you want to snap elements, check this out http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#snap-to